# Use MYSQL date function while inserting data in codeigniteruse

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to use mysql function date while inserting data in codeigniter like this:

```
for($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
   $data = array('my_date'=>'DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL '.$i.' MONTH)');

   $this->db->insert($data);
}
```

i try that code, but doesn't work, any help??

Comment: Looks correct. Can you show us the output of `var_dump($this->db->_error_message());` after the insert line?

Comment: BTW aren't you missing the first parameter to `->insert` which should be the table name?

Comment: There is no error, everything is fine, but the data in database is not valid (0000/00/00).oh yes, i miss, but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use MySQL's DATE function, use php's date() instead.

Answer (score 0):

that would work

```
for($i=1; $i<4; $i++) {
   $data = array('my_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+' . $i . ' month')));

   $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
}
```